# I want to read a single element of an XML file and output it to an aspx control

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

My XML looks like this:

```
<product id="1">
    <name>A thing</name>
    <description>This is what it's like</description>
</product>
```

I've been looking for an example that might look something like this:

```
string productID = 1;
XDocument productsXML = XDocument.Load("Products.xml");
for item in productsXML {
    if (item.ID == productID) {
        productNameLabel.Text = item.name;
    }
}
```

The idea being, I'll be able to output a single xml child element to the .aspx page.

```
A thing
```

Does that make sense? I've been looking for examples for a few hours, and I'm starting to think that there is lot more scaffolding that I need, but since all the examples are so different, I'm not sure which one to follow!

So, how can I grab the contents of a single XML child element, and output it to the .aspx? Take this:

```
<product id="1">
    <name>A thing</name>
    <description>This is what it's like</description
</product>
```

and output this:

```
A thing
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use XPath (in `System.Xml.XPath`)

```
string value = productsXML.XPathSelectElement("//product[@id='1']/name").Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I agree with L.B.'s answer since it is rather simple.  If you like Linq (I noticed you were using XDocument, which is a Linq to XML object), here's an alternative solution:

```
XDocument productsXML = XDocument.Load("Products.xml");
        string item = productsXML.Elements("product")
                                 .Where(p => p.Attribute("id").Value == productID)
                                 .First()
                                 .Element("name").Value;
```

`productsXML.Elements("product")` This gets all product nodes in the document.
`.Where(p => p.Attribute("id").Value == productID)` This gets only the product node(s) with the `id` that matches your productiD.
`.First()` Since the `.Where` function returns a collection of nodes, this grabs the first one. 
`.Element("name").Value;` This finds an element within the product node called `name` and returns its value.

For such a simple schema, the XPath seems much less verbose, but a bit harder to understand if you don't know XPath in the first place.  Linq is a lot more lines of code (in this instance), but is a lot more readable if you don't know XPath.